# In John 9:7 how did the blind man go to the pool of Siloam, after being sent by Jesus to do so when he was blind he couldn't see the way through

Tags: john

In John 9:7, how did the blind man go to the pool of Siloam, after being sent by Jesus to do so when he was blind he couldn't see the way through?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you haven't done so already, check out the [site tour.](http://goo.gl/5U2gsX) If you decide you want to answer any questions, Please note that "showing your work" is [required](http://goo.gl/BoMPLJ) for answers to be considered "good" and get upvotes from the community on this Stack Exchange.

Comment: Presumably the same way blind people generally get around - with the help of others.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the beginning of Ch.9 chronologically follows the end of Ch.8, it would be likely that Jesus found the man in the vicinity of the Pool of Siloam. The pool is located just outside of the temple mount complex, and Jesus leaves the temple at the end of Ch.8, thus if Jesus left the temple he may have come to the Pool immediately afterward and found the man there. It would also make sense for the blind man to be there, as sources of water were social centers and well trafficked areas for the needy to ask for charity.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it, it is Jesus' powerful words and anointing that he was able to get there. He was doing what he was told, therefore his footsteps were already order. The steps of a good man are ordered by the LORD.
I hope this helps

Comment: Hello Kiesha, welcome to BHSE, so glad to have you with us! If you haven't already, make sure to take our tour to get yourself familiar with this site, you'll discover that we are a little different than other sites you know. (hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) Thanks!